# automorphism group of a group of order $p^2$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

There is a corollary that states:

"If $|P|=p^2$ for some prime $p$, then $P$ is abelian. More precisely, $P$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$."

I know that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, which has order $p(p-1)^2(p+1)$, so |Aut($P$)|=$p(p-1)^2(p+1)$ if $P \cong \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

What if $P\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$? I know that then |Aut($P$)|$=p(p-1)$, but I don't know why. What is Aut($\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$)?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: An automorphism is uniquely determined by where it sends a generator. Which images of a generator will result in an automorphism?

Comment: Yeah, you have in fact done the harder case first. A cyclic group has an easy automorphism group. Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, the image of a generator under an automorphism should behave like a generator of the group, so I would think that either generators get mapped to themselves or to other generators.

Comment: Yes, precisely. So if $x$ is some generator, which powers of $x$ will also be generators?

Answer (score 1):

$\phi \in $ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$) is uniquely determined by the image of a generator, which must be another generator.

The generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ are $\phi(p^2) = p(p-1)$ where $\phi$ is the Euler function, and so $$ |\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}) | = p(p-1)$$